# Keeping Squares Along A Circle's Circumference

Tags: ios, uikit, geometry

I'm drawing squares along a circular path for an iOS application. However, at certain points along the circle, the squares start to go out of the circle's circumference. How do I make sure that the squares stay inside?

[image]

Here's an illustration I made. The green squares represent the positions I need the squares to actually be in. The red squares are where they actually appear given the following values for each square's upper-left corner:

```
x = origin.x + radius * cos(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle));
y = origin.y + radius * sin(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle));
```

Origin refers to the center of the circle. I have a loop that repeats this for every angle from 1 till 360 degrees.

EDIT: I've changed my design to position the centers of the squares along the circular path rather than their upper left corners.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ryan cumley's answer made me realize how dumb I was all along. I just needed to change each square's anchor point to its center & that solved it. Now every calculated value for x & y would position every square's center exactly on the circular path.

Comment: Don't ever feel "dumb" about a solution you've come up with, there are always many acceptable ways to accomplish most tasks, and many times functional is better than clever. Glad it worked for you

Answer (score 1):

why not just draw the centers of the squares along a smaller circle inside of the bigger one?

You could do the math to figure out exactly what the radius would have to be to ensure an exact fit, but you could probably trial and error your way there quickly too.

Doing it this way ensures that your objects would end up laid out in an actual circle too, which is not the case if you were merely making sure that one and only one corner of each square touched the larger bounding circle (that would create a slightly octagonal shape instead of a circle)

Comment: Great! Feel free to mark it as the answer you chose so people who visit this question later know what you picked!

Answer (score 0):

Option 1) You could always find the diameter of the circle and then using Pythagorean Theorem, you could create a square that would fit perfectly within the circle. You could then loop through the square that was just made in the circle to create smaller squares, but I doubt this is what you are aiming for.

Option2) Find out what half of the length of one of the diagonals of the squares should be, and create a ring within the first ring. Then lay down squares at key points (like ever 30 degrees or 15 degrees, etc) along the inner path. Ex: https://i.stack.imgur.com/igY83.png
As you can see, the smaller (inner) circle is in the center of each green square, and that ensures that the corners of each square just touches the larger (outer) circle. Obviously my cheaply made picture in paint is not perfect, but mathematically it will work.